# How can I enter datetime as 01/01/2018 this is like dd/mm/yy

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2012, how can I restrict a user? He should enter date like dd/mm/yyy

```
Create table Dummyform 
(
    Id int, 
    Entrydate datetime
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entering a date time value is a matter of the UI. If you are entering the date directly on a UI like SSMS using a character value then you should enter it in a format that doesn't depend on server settings like ODBC canonical format. A safe format is 'yyyyMMdd' for date and 'yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss' for datetime. Other formats are server settings dependent.

If you are entering the date outside SQL server then you should simply send it as a parameter of type date or datetime (or if need to send as a string then again as the above format).